# Reference script variable in function

Tags: r, variables, escaping

I work on a script which I want to apply to multiple outcome variables which I try to define in the beginning of the script and then be able to modify it easily

at the beginning I have something like

```
outcome_variable <<- "parameter244"
```

In most components of my script it works if I simply use outcome_variable from then on instead of parameter244 but in the following function it doesn't work – I think I have to escape the variable somehow...

```
index.training <- createDataPartition(analyze_data.norm$outcome_variable, p = 0.8, list = FALSE) %>% as.vector()
```

it works with

```
index.training <- createDataPartition(analyze_data.norm$parameter244, p = 0.8, list = FALSE) %>% as.vector()
```

Comment: Use `analyze_data.norm[[outcome_variable]]`

Comment: Thanks!
But how to use the outcome_variable in a option of another function?
e.g.

ggplot(aes(x = feature, y = value, fill = outcome_variable))
ggplot(aes(x = feature, y = value, fill = get(outcome_variable)))

both do not work, the graph title is just "outcome_variable" and not "parameter244"